# Which direction of dropout should I order for small parts kit for SHIMANO ALFINE internal hub gears

Tags: internally-geared-hub

The bike I have is Raleigh Motus ebike 2018.

I have ordered a SHIMANO ALFINE SG-S7001-8 internal gear hub to replace the stock derailleurs there.

I need to order a small parts set SM-S7000-8. It comes in 3 flavours vertical, horizontal and standard.
I'm not sure which one I need.

If it has anything to do with the current cable run - that follows the chain stay to the rear of the bike and then does a 180 degree turn into the derailleurs. If it is the way the wheel slots in then currently the wheel drops out below down mostly at a slight angle towards the front on the bike.

Which part should I order?

Comment: Search the hub model at si.shimano.com. You'll find a diagram that shows the cable and dropout permutations that go with each kit. It may be in the dealer manual pdf.

Comment: this is the dealer manual https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-SG0004-05-ENG.pdf

Comment: Page 16 seems to be in the right sort of area - mentions vertical ... no mention of horizontal, or small parts kit. Variations possibly related to whether cable tensioner is in use